# Make object attribute displayabe instead of object django

Tags: python, django, admin

In django admin, I have a model in which there are several objects. Now in admin, I have the link to Mymodel. If i click that, I get a list, all of which say

```
Mymodel object
```

If I need to find a particular record from the table, then I simply have to search the whole list. How can I change the setting so that instead of `MyModel object` I get to see an attribute, say name of that particular object??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define `__unicode__` method in your model class:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name # to display name attribute
```

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__):

> The `__unicode__()` method is called whenever you call unicode() on an
>   object. Django uses unicode(obj) (or the related function, str(obj))
>   in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the
>   Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it
>   displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice,
>   human-readable representation of the model from the `__unicode__()`
>   method.

Comment: Should I syncdb again?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh no, no changes in db